# WARN [main] 2017-12-01 18:17:40,014 Gossiper.java:1415 - Unable to gossip with any seeds but continuing since node is in its own seed list

Tags: cassandra

insyalled cassandra i see all the 6 nodes up and running. but during the startup i see this alert "WARN  [main] 2017-12-01 18:17:40,014 Gossiper.java:1415 - Unable to gossip with any seeds but continuing since node is in its own seed list" can any one explain me why are we getting this warning during the startup

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to gossip with any seeds but continuing since node is in its own seed list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45584748/unable-to-gossip-with-any-seeds-but-continuing-since-node-is-in-its-own-seed-lis)

Comment: Are you getting this message on one node or on all nodes?

Comment: @AlexOtt I see all the nodes up and running only thing i'm noticing is whenever the node comes it says this

Comment: @SimonFontanaOscarsson i'm seeing on all nodes

Comment: @cad I'm not sure how new you are to Cassandra so this might be a stupid question. But what does 'nodetool status' output on one of the nodes? Can you see that all nodes are connected to the same cluster?